# Why does a ring homomorphism not necessarily map unit to unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm having trouble understanding why in a ring homomorphism, say maps from $R$ to $R'$, doesn't necessarily map the unit $1$ in $R$ to $1'$ in $R'$. If you use the definition that it preserves multiplication: $H(1a) = H(1)H(a)$ for some $a \in R$, does this not imply $H(1)$ is the unit in $R'$? Or is this because the multiplication is not necessarily commutative? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

If $f:R\to S$ is a map that respects addition and multiplication, then we have, for all $a\in R$:

$$f(a) = f(1)f(a) = f(a)f(1)$$

This says that $f(1)$ is an identity element of the ring $f(R)$.  But this doesn't need to be the same as the identity element of $S$.

For example, the zero map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ certainly maps $1$ to the identity of the ring $\{0\}$, but not to the identity of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : $f:R\to R'$ defined by $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in R$.

This satisfies all the ring homomorphism axioms, except that $f(1)\neq 1$ (except if $R'$ is the zero ring of course).

Answer (score 1):

A non-trivial example for a homomorphism with $1$ not to $1'$ is
$f:Z_2\to Z_{4n+2}$ with $0\mapsto 0$, $1\mapsto 2n+1$.

Obviously $f(a)+f(b)=f(a+b)$ and $f(0)f(b)=0=f(0b)$, and $$f(1)f(1)=4n^2+4n+1=2n+1=f(1),$$ which certify $f$ is a ring homomorphism.

Comment: $Z_n$ (or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb Z$ being integers) is [ring of integers modulo n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n). Its elements are ${0, 1, 2, ..., n-1}$ with $+$ and $\times$ as usual integer but with modulo $n$.

Answer (score 0):

In general zero-homomorphism $H$ is not satisfy the relation $H(1_R) = H(1_{R'})$.
But this is true for *surjective* homomorphism $H$.